# ¿Como puedo mantener una imagen agregando un scroll usando Vue?

Tags: css, html5, vue.js, vuetify

Buenas espero una pronta ayuda, tengo problemas al momento de agregar un scroll a lado de una imagen, la imagen mencionada pareciera que su height aumentara a pesar que le de un alto fijo que es heigth: 100%, si agrego mucho mas contenido dentro del scroll.

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout column fill-height>
      <v-flex>
        <cabecera></cabecera>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex>
        <v-layout row wrap fill-height>
          <!-- IMAGEN -->
          <v-flex xs8 pa-4 style="position: relative;">
            <v-img
              style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"
              src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nnfeBcDwuRw/maxresdefault.jpg"
            ></v-img>
            <!-- Switch button -->
            <v-flex class="switch white--text">
              <v-layout column justify-center align-center fill-height>
                <h1 class="text-xs-center subheading mb-2" style="cursor: pointer;">3D</h1>
                <tr style=" background: white; height: 2px; width: 100%"></tr>
                <h1 class="text-xs-center subheading mt-2" style="cursor: pointer;">IMG</h1>
              </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
            <!-- imagen button -->
            <v-flex class="image_button">botones</v-flex>
          </v-flex>

          <!-- Issues List -->
          <v-flex xs4 pa-4>
            <!-- CANTIDAD Y FILTRO DE ISSUES -->
            <v-layout row align-center>
              <v-flex>
                <span class="text-xs-center subheading">24 issues</span>
              </v-flex>

              <v-flex class="text-xs-right" mr-4>
                <v-tooltip top>
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <v-btn
                      class="headline boton-redondear"
                      depressed
                      large
                      color="secondary"
                      style="min-width: 17%; margin-right: 10px !important;"
                      v-on="on"
                      disabled
                    >
                      <v-icon>fa-info-circle</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                  </template>
                  <span style="padding: 1em;">Información</span>
                </v-tooltip>

                <v-tooltip top>
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <v-btn
                      class="headline boton-redondear"
                      depressed
                      large
                      color="secondary"
                      style="min-width: 17%;"
                      v-on="on"
                      @click="mostrarFiltro = !mostrarFiltro"
                    >F</v-btn>
                  </template>
                  <span style="padding: 1em;">Filtrar Issues</span>
                </v-tooltip>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>

            <!-- Show view Issues List -->
            <v-layout v-if="mostrarFiltro" row wrap  class="scroll" pr-2>
              <!-- ISSUES POR TRABAJADOR -->
              <v-flex class="IssuesClickable" xs12 sm6 md12 lg12 xl12 mt-3>
                <v-layout row class="text-xs-center border-cuerpo">
                  <v-flex xs3 my-2 ml-2>
                    <v-img
                      class="imagen-cuerpo"
                      mx-auto
                      src="https://imagina.pe/uploads/portadas/fachada-smart-920x842-min.jpg"
                    ></v-img>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 mt-2>
                    <v-layout row style="margin-bottom: -11px;">
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Id: 1</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex class="text-xs-right" mr-3>
                        <v-chip
                          style="height: 50%; font-size: smaller;"
                          color="success"
                          text-color="white"
                        >Resuelto</v-chip>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row>
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Nombre Apellido</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex class="text-xs-right" mr-3>
                        <v-chip
                          style="height: 40%; font-size: xx-small;"
                          color="error"
                          text-color="white"
                        >
                          <span>RDI</span>
                        </v-chip>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row style="margin-top: -8px; font-weight: bold;">
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Cruce entre luminaria y detector de humo</p>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row style>
                      <v-flex>
                        <p
                          class="text-xs-left"
                          style="font-size: small;"
                        >El plano de desarrollo de montantes no se aprecian las montantes de Ventilación y Desagüe N°4.</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex style="align-self: flex-end;" mr-2>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">02/07/2019</p>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-flex>

              <v-flex class="IssuesClickable" xs12 sm6 md12 lg12 xl12 mt-3>
                <v-layout row class="text-xs-center border-cuerpo">
                  <v-flex xs3 my-2 ml-2>
                    <v-img
                      class="imagen-cuerpo"
                      mx-auto
                      src="https://imagina.pe/uploads/portadas/fachada-smart-920x842-min.jpg"
                    ></v-img>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 mt-2>
                    <v-layout row style="margin-bottom: -11px;">
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Id: 2</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex class="text-xs-right" mr-3>
                        <v-chip
                          style="height: 50%; font-size: smaller;"
                          color="warning"
                          text-color="white"
                        >En progreso</v-chip>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row>
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Nombre Apellido</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex class="text-xs-right" mr-3>
                        <v-chip
                          style="height: 40%; font-size: xx-small;"
                          color="secondary"
                          text-color="white"
                          @click="$router.push('/issuesrdi')"
                        >
                          <span style="cursor: pointer;">RDI</span>
                        </v-chip>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row style="margin-top: -8px; font-weight: bold;">
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Cruce entre luminaria y detector de humo</p>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row style>
                      <v-flex>
                        <p
                          class="text-xs-left"
                          style="font-size: small;"
                        >El plano de desarrollo de montantes no se aprecian las montantes de Ventilación y Desagüe N°4.</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex style="align-self: flex-end;" mr-2>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">02/07/2019</p>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-flex>

              <v-flex class="IssuesClickable" xs12 sm6 md12 lg12 xl12 mt-3>
                <v-layout row class="text-xs-center border-cuerpo">
                  <v-flex xs3 my-2 ml-2>
                    <v-img
                      class="imagen-cuerpo"
                      mx-auto
                      src="https://imagina.pe/uploads/portadas/fachada-smart-920x842-min.jpg"
                    ></v-img>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 mt-2>
                    <v-layout row style="margin-bottom: -11px;">
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Id: 3</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex class="text-xs-right" mr-3>
                        <v-chip
                          style="height: 50%; font-size: smaller;"
                          color="secondary"
                          text-color="white"
                        >Desestimado</v-chip>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row>
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Nombre Apellido</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex class="text-xs-right" mr-3>
                        <v-chip
                          style="height: 40%; font-size: xx-small;"
                          color="secondary"
                          text-color="white"
                          @click="$router.push('/issuesrdi')"
                        >
                          <span style="cursor: pointer;">RDI</span>
                        </v-chip>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row style="margin-top: -8px; font-weight: bold;">
                      <v-flex>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">Cruce entre luminaria y detector de humo</p>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row style>
                      <v-flex>
                        <p
                          class="text-xs-left"
                          style="font-size: small;"
                        >El plano de desarrollo de montantes no se aprecian las montantes de Ventilación y Desagüe N°4.</p>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex style="align-self: flex-end;" mr-2>
                        <p class="text-xs-left">02/07/2019</p>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-flex>


            </v-layout>



          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

La idea es tener mas contenido dentro del scroll, y su función sea de manera independiente, sin necesidad que se alargue la imagen porque ya ocupa su alto al tope.

[image: Imagen del problema]

Tan solo tener 3 contenidos dentro del scroll, la imagen mantiene su alto de manera normal.

[image: Imagen sin contenido de datos]

Les agredeceria muchísimo con su ayuda,  gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podes aclarar que componentes estas usando? no deberian ser dos componentes separados? uno de la foto y otro que haga el scroll? dentro de tu diseño, podes especificar cual es cual?

Comment: En esta ocasión no uso componentes solo estoy usando grillas

Comment: Por componente me referia a que es v- (supongo que sera vuetify pero no puedo asegurarlo). Y otra cosa, si eso es una grilla, donde definis la imagen y el tamaño de la celda? Y el scroll esta dentro de la celda o fuera?

Comment: Correcto es vuetify, y acabo de agregar toda la estructura agregando los comentarios de cada sección.